# Excel VBA append a validation list

Tags: list, validation, excel, append, vba

I have a list validation that I am creating in excel VBA which is based on a set of data from a range. I then want to add to the list with a set of data from a second range of data. I thought the modify function might work, but all I receive in the list is the data from the first range.

I have a list on a worksheet that I am referring to that makes up the range. The range has a column for the WCGroupName and a column with unique data.

For example the column on the left is the groups, the column on the right separated by -- is the list:

GROUP --         LIST

EXTRUDERS   --     10-EXTRUDER
EXTRUDERS   --     15-EXTRUDER 80
MOUNT   --     20-MOUNTER
PRESS   --     30-PRESS BONARDI
BOTTOMSIDE  --     42-BOTTOMSEAL
BOTTOMSIDE  --     72-SIDEWELD 
BOTTOMPUNCH --     73-SIDEWELD2
BOTTOMSEAL  --     40-BOTTOMSEAL
WICKET  --     60-WICKET
WICKET  --     62-WICKET

I want the validation list to show the 4 items in the list. The code below only shows the first 2. I am basically trying to append the list so it shows

42-BOTTOMSEAL, 72-SIDEWELD, 73-SIDEWELD2, 40-BOTTOMSEAL

in a drop down list. This code is nestled inside another loop that is going through all of the WCGROUPNAMEs and creating mulitple validation lists. However, I need the validation list assigned to cell B23 on worksheet br to be added, then appended.

Let me know if this is even possible.

I have modified my code insert to show a broader scope of what I'm doing.
The GetUniqueWCGroup is a function that creates a piped list.

```
'This section will create the list lookups for each WC type
WCGroup = GetUniqueWCGroup()
WCGroupArray = Split(WCGroup, "|")

'Create a report for each team
For Each tmp In WCGroupArray

    WCGroupName = CStr(tmp)
    wg = WCGroupName
    'identify last row for the group
    wc.Activate
    frwg = lrwg + 1
    lrwg = xlLastRowWCGroup(wg)

    If WCGroupName = "MOUNT" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B21:B21")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

    End If 'WCGroup Mounter

    If WCGroupName = "PRESS" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B22:B22")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With
    End If 'WCGroup Press

    If WCGroupName = "BOTTOMSEAL" Or WCGroupName = "BOTTOMSIDE" Then

        If bc = 1 Then

            Set l = br.Range("B23:B23")
            Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

            With l.Validation
                .Delete 'delete previous validation
                .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
            End With

            bc = bc + 1
        Else

            Set l = br.Range("B23:B23")
            Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

            With l.Validation
                '.Delete 'delete previous validation
                .Modify Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                    Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
            End With

        End If


    End If 'WCGroup BottomSeal or BottomSide

    If WCGroupName = "WICKET" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B24:B24")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With
    End If 'WCGroup Wicket

    If WCGroupName = "BOTTOMSIDE" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B25:B25")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With
    End If 'WCGroup BottomSide

    If WCGroupName = "SLITTER" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B26:B26")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With
    End If 'WCGroup Slitting

    If WCGroupName = "PERFORATOR" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B27:B27")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

    End If 'Perforator

    If WCGroupName = "OP" Then

        Set l = br.Range("B29:B29")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

        Set l = br.Range("B30:B30")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

        Set l = br.Range("B31:B31")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

        Set l = br.Range("B32:B32")
        Set R = wc.Range("B" & frwg & ":B" & lrwg)

        With l.Validation
            .Delete 'delete previous validation
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
                Formula1:="='" & wc.Name & "'!" & R.Address
        End With

    End If 'OP

Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you may know, there are *two* ways to create a **DV** list:

1. worksheet cells
2. comma separated string (css)

the second way is like:

```
.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="larry,moe,curley"
```

This means that if you have two or more disjoint ranges, you can create a DV list by making a single css

In this example we combine the contents of **A1:A5** and **A8:A10** into a single DV:

```
Sub DisJointDatJoint()
    Dim rDV As Range, sDV As String
    Set rDV = Range("A1:A5,A8:A10")
    sDV = ""
    For Each r In rDV
        sDV = sDV & r.Value & ","
    Next r
    sDV = Mid(sDV, 1, Len(sDV) - 1)
    With Selection.Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:=sDV
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the input. However it doesn't solve my issue. The development of the list is what is disjointed. That is, I have a group of lists which is what creates my first loop. My first loop is the WC Group which represents a range of data. I then apply that range to the validation list. Further down the road I have another range, but I want to append that range to a validation list already defined.

Comment: If you already have **DV** in a cell, pull *Formula1* into a String variable.  If the string is a simple *css* then append to it.  If the string is a real formula referring to worksheet cells, then grab the contents of those cells and append.

Comment: In another question there was a suggestion to join the ranges using a union statement. That was the trick and I got it done.